# Unable to execute sequence of SQL commands from python in a single execute

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, execute

I have an initialization script for a database in SQL Server that goes through, deletes a bunch of things, then recreates schemas, tables, stored procedures, eventually more.  The script is over 2500 lines now and will probably be at least twice that big at the end.

I'm not really happy with this.  I would like to break it down so that I can have separate code that executes specific parts, so I can 1) invoke those pieces of code from Python, and 2) check in the individual SQL pieces into GIT.  It makes sense that I would want to have a given stored procedure in a file by itself, rather than this eventual maybe 8K or 10K line monstrosity.

So my first stab is say to have an SQL file, `clean_database.sql` (real file bigger than this)

```
use [$db_name]
go
declare @schemaName varchar(500)
declare @objName varchar(500)

-- if the cursor exists, get rid of it
IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','cur')>=-1
BEGIN
 DEALLOCATE cur
END

-- Get a clean cursor of the stored procedure objects, along with the associated schema
declare cur cursor
    for select s.Name, p.Name from sys.objects p
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON p.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE p.type = 'V' and is_ms_shipped = 0 and p.name not like 'sp[_]%diagram%'
    ORDER BY s.Name, p.Name
open cur

-- go through the list generated in the last step and delete each object in turn
fetch next from cur into @schemaName,@objName
while @@fetch_status = 0`enter code here`
begin
    exec('drop view ' + @schemaName + '.' + @objName)
    -- print 'drop view ' + @schemaName + '.' + @objName
    fetch next from cur into @schemaName,@objName
end
close cur
deallocate cur
go
```

Then I invoke this with Python like this.

```
    filename = r"sql\clean_database.sql"
    with open(filename, mode='r') as f:
        raw_script = f.read()
    init_script = raw_script.replace("$db_name", config["db_name"])
    cursor.execute(init_script)
```

But this produces an error - long string of stuff I do not think would be helpful indicating that I'm using this statement incorrectly. (I'll include it at the end anyway.)

NORMALLY, when I invoke `cursor.execute()` I do it on stored procedures that already exist in the database, but ideally these scripts will execute on a database that has nothing in it (or maybe some previous test stuff that needs to be reinitialized). Simply excluding the "delete everything" parts won't fix anything, because I have some very long CREATE TABLE statements (at least one with over 200 fields).

I thought about reading line by line, but that just seems intuitively wrong.  For example, what sense does it make to execute a line inside a create table command - the line is not a full statement to execute.

I'm not sure this is possible directly from Python. I'm looking at the `sqlcmd` utility at the moment, but it's not obvious this is the right way either.  It seems to me the kind of thing I want to do is obvious and common. Is there a canonical way of doing it?

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'go'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'cur'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The variable name '@schemaName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. (134); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The variable name '@objName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. (134); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'cur'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The variable name '@schemaName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. (134); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The variable name '@objName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. (134); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'cur'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'go'. (102); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The variable name '@schemaName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. (134); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'cur'. (102)")

Comment: The error is quite clear, `Incorrect syntax near 'go'`. The `go` keyword is something that's only relevant when using `sqlcmd` or SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio). If you want to execute multiple statements in a batch then use the `;` statement terminator, e.g.: `use [$db_name]; ...`

Comment: Also, get into the habit of starting your script files and stored procedures with  `SET NOCOUNT ON;`

Comment: Ah ... when it ran in SSMS, I inferred that it was okay.  yes. After experimenting around a little, I'm thinking having the initialization script in python is good, but invoke a batch script which calls sqlcmd with relevant arguments (specific sql script name). Very helpful comments.

Comment: This code is pretty dangerous. You need to learn how to use `QUOTENAME`. Also, you could build your whole `drop` script in one shot and execute it, no need for a cursor. And if you use a cursor, use a `FAST_FORWARD` local cursor variable, it will be closed and deallocated automatically at the end of the batch

Comment: @Charlieface,  Not familiar with any of those things, but I'll look into all of them. tx